# Rails 3.1 - find using count and select as

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to do the following sql statement in rails:

```
SELECT COUNT(downloads.title) AS total, downloads.title FROM `downloads` WHERE `downloads`.`member_id` = 60 Group by `downloads`.`title`
```

I wrote this in rails like this:

```
Download.where(:member_id => id).select("COUNT(downloads.title) AS total, downloads.title").group(:title)
```

If I run the query straight from the sql server the sql executes correctly but if I run the activerecord version I only get the title back.

I thought this might be because of attr_accessible but this doesnt seem to have made a difference.

any ideas ?

Comment: you can check final SQL query with `to_sql` method.

Comment: Thanks, thats a handy method but the outputted sql is as I expected but I cant work out why its not including total in the outputted object

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you tried to call `total` method on the collection object ?
This information is not included in the output for object using `to_s` method, so you probably just do not see it, but total value is there.

```
downloads = Download.where(:member_id => id).select("COUNT(downloads.title) AS total, downloads.title").group(:title)
downloads.first.total
```

Comment: Thanks, totally forgot .inspect doesnt return all the fields!

Comment: Thanks. It's helful for me.