# rails active-record: retrieve and combine similar data from two different tables/sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

In my new rails (4.1) app, I have two data models:

1. Daily aggregated data (e.g., fields "sales", "date", ...), which is filled until yesterday
2. "Live" data from an API, fetched every minute, with same content but named differently (e.g., fields "revenue", "timestamp", ...)

In one view, I want to display the daily data (1) + the current (last) value for today, which is the last value from the live stream (2) - this then updates whenever a user reloads.

Problem is, that naming in two tables is quite different, and also some data fields vary, so

```
data = daily_data + current_data.last
```

doesn't work. My thinking is as follows:

1. Take only the columns in question:

   ```
   daily_data.select("sales, date")
   live_data.select("revenue, timestamp").last
   ```
2. Modify timestamp to date

   ```
   live_data.timestamp.to_date
   ```
3. Match "Sales" to "Revenue" and merge/combine the two (for the view only, not in ActiveRecord)

Is my thinking ok? How should I go about implementing it? Am I missing something on Associations? (I also ventured into Single Table Inheritance and thought about defining a parent data model "company_data", and make both daily_data and live_data sub-models of it, but that may be overkill -or is it?)

**EDIT:**

After the operation, I plan to use

```
.group_by_date
```

to display the data as a chart with ChartKick.

*EDIT end*

Sorry if the question is dumb, I'm still new at rails and searched for 1.5h...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
daily_data.select("sales as revenue, date as datadate")
live_data.select("revenue, timestamp as datadate").last
```

This way in both cases the attributes will be revenue and datadate.

EDIT:

Your comment about the group_by is additional information not in the original question.  Since group_by is evaluated by the database, you still need to send it the field names used in the database.  The select solution only changes the attributes in the ActiveRecord objects.

```
@data = daily_data.select("sales as revenue, date as datadate").group_by_date(:date)
@data << live_data.select("revenue, timestamp as datadate").last
```

Comment: I wish it just worked, when I try to pass the data for a chart, e.g. chart_data = daily_data.select("sales as revenue, date as datadate") then chart_data.group_by_day(:datadate).sum(:revenue) fails, while daily_data.group_by_day(:date).sum(:sales) still works. (funny enough in debugger chart_data.inspect doesn't show values for "revenue" and "datadate", but chart_data[:revenue].first has a value (found that out via [this StackO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048987/rails-3-1-find-using-count-and-select-as) ). Would you be able to have another quick look at this? Thank you!!

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it to work now! Learned a lot as well. Sorry for not specifying the group_by_data need earlier, thought it wasn't part of the issue initially. Also updated the question.